# PermissionSetId and Name when queried not valid PS

Tags: soql, permission-sets

When querying the PermissionSetAssignment table, I'm getting a very strange result:

```
SELECT Id, AssigneeId, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE  AssigneeId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

This is my result:
[image]

Anybody know what that third row is all about? It's definitely not a permission set that has been created, my only guess would be some sort of container record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row that you have highlighted is a profile.  To get it's name, you will want to use:

```
SELECT Id, AssigneeId, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Profile.Name
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE  AssigneeId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

If you want only permissionsets, you can use PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = false in your query.

Comment: I see, so it represents the permissions associated with the user's profile?

Comment: That's correct.  Every permission that a user receives is recorded in the PermissionSet table.  It's an amalgamation of permission sets + profiles.  For the architecture, there is a great overview here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm